# Oracle Listagg function returns null

Tags: oracle, join, listagg

The good_name column is null for all results.What is problem in the query?

```
select fp.id,
   listagg(fpg.name, ',') within group(order by fpg.name) good_name
from fp_place_goods fppg join 
   fp_places fp on fppg.place_id = fp.id join
   fp_goods fpg on fppg.good_id = fpg.id
GROUP BY fp.id

however query below works

select fp.id,
   listagg(fpg.id, ',') within group(order by fpg.id) good_ids
from fp_place_goods fppg join 
   fp_places fp on fppg.place_id = fp.id join
   fp_goods fpg on fppg.good_id = fpg.id
GROUP BY fp.id




select fp.id, fpg.name from fp_places fp join
      fp_place_goods fppg on fp.id = fppg.place_id join
      fp_goods fpg on fpg.id = fppg.good_id
```

return the result in image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y16G3.png]

Comment: The query looks OK. Can you reproduce the problem on some test data that you can share with the forum? Also, did you try to run this with select fp.id, fpg.name from  ...  to see what the join looks like in the first place?

Comment: join works perfectly, and max() function works on fpg.name but i cant find what is missing to use listagg.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It happened because good_name is nvarchar, and to_char(fpg.name) solved it.